# How to prevent a job from sending mailers more than once per hour?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails app hosted on Heroku. Every hour, Heroku Scheduler looks for events that begin between 23 and 24 hours in the future and sends a reminder email to the participants. This usually works perfectly but recently, an event reminder was sent 7 times within an hour. My guess is because the server was reset a few times within that hour. What is the best way to keep this from happening in the future? I'm thinking about making a database table to keep track of when the last reminder job was run to avoid the jobs from running more than once per hour. Is this a sound approach?

Answer (score 0):

If there's only ever going to be one reminder you could store a simple bool in the database on the same table that stores the event something like hashadreminder.

Edit:

Reread the question a few times

If you want to do it on a participant basis then a different table with participant Id and the bool would work best to ensure that if not everyone gets the email on the first run then they do on subsequent ones.